# Нужны ли точки в названиях?

Tags: оформление-текста

Выступление на конференции оформляется в сборнике в следующем виде.
Конференция "Название"
Организатор: Название организатора(.)
Тема выступления: Название(.)
Текст выступления.
Нужны ли точки в скобках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если каждая строка с абзаца и всё етое хозяйство отцентровано - никаких точек.

И смотри: первые три позиции нависают над телом основного текста, так? Они смотрятся, а возможно и работают, заголовками. Какие точки тут могут быть, о.

Но если рассматривать каждую строку как самостоятельное предложение, то таки да, на точках.

Comment: Этот ответ меня устраивает (подтверждает первоначальное отсутствие точек), никаких точек! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если строки этих позиций неполны, точек может не быть; при полных (или более одной) — точки обязательны.

В любом случае следует обеспечить однотипность решения строк.

Comment: Не понятно, что значит "строки этих позиций неполны". Хотелось бы обеспечить однотипность в соответствии с правилами (если они есть и строги).

Comment: Однотипность решения строк = одинаковый подход в стилистике, пунктуации, размерности, выравниванию. Полная строка — строка враспор по ширине столбца. Более одной строки может дать и название темы, и название организации.

Comment: Не понятно, почему несколько строк ТРЕБУЮТ точки (это правило?). Тем более если каждый пункт - с абзаца. По-моему, другой ответ всё объясняет.

Comment: Объясняет, потому что устраивает, подтверждает, и основан на правилах, а они есть и строги как известно. Ваш вопрос общий, т. е. со многими неизвестными, и отвечать не представляя макет трудно. Первые две позиции я бы вывел на шмуцтитул. Темы выступлений и указания на авторство — на единообразные начальные перед их текстами.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. До верстки (макета) дело еще не дошло.